# Drupal 7 add contact_site_form to a block but only one category

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have two categories set up in my site wide contact forms:

- General
- Technical

I want to embed the general form in a block. I have this code that works for loading the form:

```
<?php
  require_once drupal_get_path('module', 'contact') .'/contact.pages.inc';
$form = drupal_get_form('contact_site_form');
  print render($form);
?>
```

But I only want to load the `General` form and not have the drop down select list.

I installed the `Contact Forms` modules which give me access to the forms seperatly so I know it can be done. This module didn't help with this situation thoigh as the forms still have the same ID.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, This modules did the job...

http://drupal.org/project/contact_form_blocks

Comment: this is no solution when using D7!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use other variables in form alter for this. Based on some variable we can alter a given form only in particular case. For example $_GET['q'] of contact page is 'contact'. You can check this and set default value for form category select list only if  `$_GET['q'] != 'contact'`, then hide a select list with `'#type' => 'hidden'`.

Comment: Thanks @Sergey. I actuay found a module that did the job I needed. Your answer was still helpful. thanks.

Comment: @Cybercampbell Please mention the module name that solved your problem.

Comment: @MiladRey, http://drupal.org/project/contact_form_blocks, see please previous answer with green mark.